# Query to update main form from sub form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Let me say I have no idea how to work Access. I use C# coding. Now that is out of the way, I have been given the task to make a Access Database. Lotta crashes so far. So, I have a table, and 2 sub forms. My first form lets me add new records and update existing records. My 2nd form only updates existing records.  My 1st form I want it too be able to click in the text box and edit/add a record. Right now I keep getting Error 3075, need a operator. I also have a button that adds a record, and it's giving me the same issue as well. I'm not sure how to even decipher this. Here is my code for my Event procedure and my button which is also a event procedure.  I have a primary key that Auto numbers as well. I was told all databases need a Primary Key. If I need to explain this better I can, as I'm not familiar with the workings of access, this is where I'm at.

My click Code-
`DoCmd.OpenForm "Calibration Detail", , , " '[CalibrationKey]= ' " & [CalibrationKey], acFormEdit, acDialog`

My button code -
`DoCmd.OpenForm "Calibration Detail", , , " '[CalibrationKey]= ' " & [CalibrationKey], acFormAdd, acDialog`

Comment: Remove the apostrophes. Is CalibrationKey the autonumber field?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's my Primary Key. I removed the apostrophes, and it's working for now. Do I need to take the brackets off of ` & [CalibrationKey]`?

Comment: No. They are necessary if name includes space or punctuation/special characters, but they won't hurt to use anyway. Actually, for the concatenated field I would use Me.CalibrationKey.

Comment: I'll try that out, thank you.

Comment: @June7 So I should put  " [CalibrationKey]= " & [Me.CalibrationKey]

Comment: @Airizzo No use`"[CalibrationKey]= " & Me.[CalibrationKey]`unless you named your control`[Me.CalibrationKey]`.Square-brackets define start/end of identifier (if dots or blanks included), but`Me`is the reference to the form.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher thank you.

Comment: As I said, [ ] not even required because there are no spaces nor punctuation/special characters.